# non-linear regression by Pytorch

Tags: python, regression, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, text-processing

I am trying to implement a non-linear regression task using PyTorch framework. The inputs are sample sentences and the targets are their scores (these scores are some float numbers). In order for the computer to understand the sentences, I convert each sentence to a 50 dimensional real vector (embedding vectors) using a `torch.nn.RNN` (Recurrent Neural Network) layer. Then I use a linear layer, `torch.nn.Linear`, to predict the score.

This is my model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pack_padded_sequence
import text_processing as tp
import torch.nn.functional as F


class RNNModel(nn.Module):
##################        __init__          ####################
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, input_size,hidden_size, output_size,my_embeddings,n_layers,bidirectional=True):
        super(RNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.n_directions = int(bidirectional) + 1

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, hidden_size)
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size,hidden_size,n_layers,bidirectional=bidirectional)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
####################          forward          #################
    def forward(self, batch_of_sentences, batch_of_len):
        """
        input shape: B x S ([num of sentences in this batch] x [max sent len in this batch] )
        transpose to make S x B
        """
        input=batch_of_sentences
        input = input.t()
        batch_size = input.size(1)

        # Make a hidden
        hidden = self._init_hidden(batch_size)

        # Embedding S x B -> S x B x I (embedding size)
        embedded = self.embedding(input)
        # Pack them up nicely
        rnn_input = pack_padded_sequence(embedded, batch_of_len.data.cpu().numpy())

        # To compact weights again call flatten_parameters().
        self.rnn.flatten_parameters()
        output, hidden = self.rnn(rnn_input, hidden)
        fc_output = self.fc(hidden[-1])
        return fc_output

##################          _init_hidden          ##################
    def _init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        hidden = torch.zeros(self.n_layers * self.n_directions,
                             batch_size, self.hidden_size)
        return tp.create_variable(hidden)
```

I have called the model in the main program:

```
my_rnn_model = RNNModel(VOCAB_SIZE,INPUT_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE,OUTPUT_SIZE, tp.my_embeddings_train_dev,N_LAYERS, bidirectional=True)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(size_average=False)
LR = 0.001
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(my_rnn_model.parameters(), lr=LR, betas=(0.9, 0.99)
for epoch in range(1, N_EPOCHS + 1):
   loss=train()
```

Here is train() function:

```
def train():

    #Loading Data From TrainLoader
    for i, (batch_sents, batch_target_scores) in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
        #Zero Padding
        zero_padded_batch_sent, sorted_batch_len, sorted_batch_target_scores = tp.make_variables(batch_sents, batch_target_scores,"train")

        #Compute Output for Each Batch of Sentences
        output = my_rnn_model(zero_padded_batch_sent, sorted_batch_len)

        #Compute Loss
        loss = criterion(output, sorted_batch_target_scores)

        #Updating Parameters by Backward Propagation
        my_rnn_model.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

But I think that my model can not learn the data, because after training the model for 30 epochs, the loss plot for train and test data is fluctuating and looks unstable, whereas, I expect the error to converge over time and not to have oscillating behavior.

Here is my loss vs. training plot for train and test data during 30 epochs:
[image]

Which part of my code is wrong?